# fullcalendar doesn't render properly after opening a modal

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, vuejs3

I'm currently using fullcalendar on my project. The calendar kinda works however when I load the calendar after a button click it doesn't render properly. However if I open dev-tools which moves the modal slightly it appears to render. Or if I press a button to change the month for example it appears normally.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zszZi.jpg

Here is what controls the modal opening and closing.

```
        modalControl()
        {
            if(this.showModal === false)
            {
                this.showModal = true
            }
            else if(this.showModal === true)
            {
                this.showModal = false
            }
        },
```

The calendar options from fullcalendar.

```
            calendarOptions: {
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                contentHeight: 'auto',
                aspectRatio: 1.5,
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Today',
                    month: 'Month',
                    week: 'Week',
                    list: 'List'
                },
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth'
                },
                selectable: true,
                weekends: true,
                dateClick: this.handleDateClick
            },
```

```
        <vue-final-modal v-model="showModal" :drag="true" :esc-to-close="true">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
                <div class="bg-backgroundWhite p-12">
                    <div class="flex justify-between">
                        <div>Book a lesson</div>
                        <button @click="modalControl">X</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row w-full h-full p-3 shadow-xl rounded-xl m-3">
                        <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </vue-final-modal>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating the calendar inside an element which is initially hidden, this will distort the calendar or cause it not to show up at all, even when that outer element is later shown. This is because at initialisation the calendar tries to size itself appropriately to its containing element (and as per its own sizing settings).

To make it re-render and thus re-size to the newly-visible element, at the time when that element has just become visible, you can run the calendar's "render" function, e.g.

```
calendar.render();
```

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render

---

N.B. I see you're using vue. I'm not a vue expert and so I can't give a vue-specific answer or tell you how what event to handle to know that the modal has just been shown, or anything like that. So I've just explained what you need to do from the fullCalendar point of view, in the hope you can build on that, and in the hope the answer maybe useful to others having the same issue with fullCalendar in any similar context.